# Edit python script without reloading libraries

Tags: python

I am working on a project that involves some huge libraries. Every time I want to make minor changes to my script, I have to reload *all* the dependencies, which takes a very long time. Is there a way to make edits and reload without reloading all the dependencies?

Possibly related, but doesn't fully answer my question:
[Auto-run a python script without reloading dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997698/auto-run-a-python-script-without-reloading-dependencies)

Comment: You can `reload` a single import, the others will be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. For other searching:

suppose I make a script called `HurrDurr`

`HurrDurr = reload(HurrDurr)` will reload just that script. So move the big dependencies to another file and make your minor changes by reloading.

Comment: Note that `reload` is no longer a built-in in Python 3. It is still available, it was just moved into a module. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/961219/40076) for more details.